# Bootstrap row-fluid doesn't nest side by side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to divide row into 2 (span4 & span8) but couldn't manage so far. The second div (span8) slides down. What I am missing?

Here is my related markup:

```
<section id="products" data-direction="from-left">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
            <h1>
                <span lang="tr">ÜRÜNLERİMİZ</span>
            </h1>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">

                        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                                <div class="row-fluid item active">

                                    <div class="bannerImage">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmote_pro_t.png" alt=""></a>
                                        <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmote_exp_radio_board_2-375_t.png" alt=""></a>
                                        <a href="#"><img src="images/u13_gw_t.png" alt=""></a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="caption row-fluid">
                                        <div class="span12">
                                            <h3>Waspmote</h3>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                            <div class="span4">
                                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                                                    <li><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Connect any sensor</li>
                                                    <li><i class="fa fa-rss"></i> Using any wireless technology</li>
                                                    <li><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> To any Cloud Platform</li>
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="span8">
                                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                                                    <li><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Connect any sensor</li>
                                                    <li><i class="fa fa-rss"></i> Using any wireless technology</li>
                                                    <li><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> To any Cloud Platform</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div><!-- /Slide1 -->



                            </div>

                            <div class="control-box">
                                <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
                                <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
                            </div><!-- /.control-box -->

                        </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

                    </div><!-- /.span12 -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->

        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is the sample screenshot:
[sample](http://s28.postimg.org/dkknj07ot/sample.png)

Here is the FF debug:
[sample](http://s22.postimg.org/foh2xedi9/sample1.png)

**edit 1: It is Bootstrap v3.2.0**

Here is my relevant custom CSS:

```
div {
    word-break: break-all;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

a {
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease;
}

    a:hover {
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
        /* IE 8 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        /* IE7 */
        opacity: 0.6;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/* Container */

.container-fluid {
    background: #fbf4e0;
    margin: 40px auto 10px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    max-width: 960px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* Page Header */

.page-header {
    background: #fbf4e0;
    margin: -30px 0px 0px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
    color: #a83b3b;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    .page-header h3 {
        line-height: 0.88rem;
        color: #a83b3b;
    }


/* Thumbnail Box */

.caption {
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .caption .span4,
    .caption .span8 {
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }

    .caption .span4 {
        border-right: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    }

    .caption h3 {
        color: #a83b3b;
        line-height: 2rem;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .caption p {
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.6rem;
        color: #a83b3b;
    }
    .caption ul{
         color: #a83b3b;
    }

.btn.btn-mini {
    background: #a83b3b;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    color: #fbf4e0;
    font-size: 0.63rem;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

.carousel-control {
    top: 33%;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.69rem;
}

    .footer,
    .footer a {
        color: #fff;
    }

p.right {
    float: right;
}


::selection {
    background: #ff5e99;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #ff5e99;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a,
a:focus,
a:active,
a:hover,
object,
embed {
    outline: none;
}

:-moz-any-link:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}

.bannerImage img {
    margin-left: 10%;
    /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}
```

edit 2: Here is the other CSS files.

```
<!-- ==============================================
       CSS
       =============================================== -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700,400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Thanks in advance & Best Regards.

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using? could you share your css too, is probable that other styles are interfering, or create a jsfiddle to troubleshoot this.

Comment: You should provide more info about the bootstrap version that you are using or the changes that you have made over bootstrap. The classnames that you are using does not seem like the bootstrap ones.

Comment: @DiegoLópez, I added relevant CSS and bootstrap version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the classes you are using for scaffolding (`row-fluid` and `span*`) are from an older [version](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html) of bootstrap.

You need to use the scaffolding classes of Bootstrap 3 for example: `container-fluid`, `row`, `col-md-*`. Check the full documentation on the Bootstrap 3 grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Example:

Instead of:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span12"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span8"></div>
     <div class="span4"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Use:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8"></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```